# How to call COM dll from c# web service using IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, com, dllimport

I wrote a web service (c#, VS2012, windows7 64bit), which calls a COM dll.
Using visual studio, there was no problem to execute the web service and thus the client's application.

After trying to locate the web service in the IIS, all calls to the COM dll's function failed.
What could be the problem? Is there any specific configuration of the IIS for COM dlls?

Comment: Most probaly a security thing. What is the application pool used for your iis app? Under which user is it running?

Comment: The application pool is .NET Framework v4.0.

Comment: Create an app pool for your app. Start it with a user having admin rights on your PC and see if things work. If they do, you know this is an authorization problem.

Comment: The user is not the administrator, but got full control permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the executing user of the app pool to a custom account instead of a built-in account. Try to run it as an administrator first and get it to work. Then try with a more restricted user account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.The user is the administrator now. What

Comment: Is there another possible reason for this problem?

Comment: Well is it still not working? Even when running it as administrator in IIS. If it is a new machine you are trying to run on ? then maybe there is something wrong with the registration of your COM dlls.

Comment: I found a possible solution "Set Isolated to False for Interop.TAPI3Lib and use .NET Framework 2.0." from a thread on CodeProject (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10994/TAPI-3-0-Application-development-using-C-NET?msg=3887840#xx3887840xx). I don't know if it's the same thing thst you are trying to do, but it it the same Error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike and David. It turns out that the dll application is 32bit. Enabling the 32-bit application solves the problem.

Comment: Great that you solved it. Should have thought about. When working with COM dlls you are often unable to use 64bit.

Comment: I am trying to copy the web service to another machine(virtual machine). In case of using the dll 32-bti application, the web service

Comment: is not loaded. In case of not using the COM dll, the web service is loaded successfully. I changed the application pool settings as in the real machine( enable 32-bit, .NET 4.0, classic...). Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi again. May be it could be the .net version. In one of my old projects, that depended much on COM-refernces, I was unable to upgrade from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0. If you don't use any 4.0-specific code try to build it in 3.5, and run it as a 2.0 application in the IIS. Could be worth a try.

Comment: I use 4.0 specific code ("microsoft.CSharp " reference). I can't build  it as 2.0 application.

Answer (score 0):

I changed Framework version from 3.5 to 4. then sloved.

ref: http://quickstartprojects.org/2011/11/webservicesindotnet4/